# htaccess redirect having the same url except destination has parameter

Tags: .htaccess, loops, redirect

We are trying to remove duplicate content from our website. We are using **Jooml**a and experiencing duplicate error mostly in our **k2blog**.

I would like to create a 301 from a page to the same page except that the destination page has a parameter in the url. Browsers show me an error (too many redirects)

This is the rule that I have created:

```
RewriteEngine on
Redirect 301 /news/date/2014/4 /news/date/2014/4?limitstart=0
```

Comment: as '/news/date/2014/4' is a part of the redirect url '/news/date/2014/4?limitstart=0' looks like it enters into a deadlock (too many redirects)

Comment: is there a way that i could redirect that link? how about append - will it work?